# creating and deleting an object (e.g. rectangle) ager a time delay repeatedly in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, delay, tkinter-canvas

I'm rather new in python. Currently I aim tot write a program which must create and delete repeatedly after a few seconds object (rectangle, circle, etc.).If I use the .after method in a separate function I get an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignmentWhen, see myself code. Alternatively, if I put the repeating code in the main part of program, it only shows the last state and not in state in between (see the description between """ and """ in the code. I searched the internet for a while but I could not sole it. I hope you can help me.

Here is an simplified version my code (actually I'm working with a list of rec's), which shows my problem:

```
import tkinter as tk


def master_field(text):
    """ work field (master) construction"""
    master.geometry('500x500+0+0') 
    master.title(text) 

def stop_button():
    """exit"""
    b = tk.Button(master, text = 'Exit', width=2, command = master.destroy)
    b.place(x = 50, y = 0, width = 100)

def built_canvas():
    """create a canvas"""
    canvas=tk.Canvas(master, width = canvas_width, height = canvas_height, borderwidth = 1, bg='light grey', highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="blue")
    canvas.place(x = 0, y = 20)
    return canvas

def update_canvas():

    while counter<10:
        canvas.delete(rec)
        rec = canvas.create_rectangle(x1+i*10,y1+i*10,x2+i*10,y2+i*10, width=0, fill="green")
        counter +=1
        master.after(500,update_canvas)


# MAIN
master = tk.Tk()
master_field('MY FIELD')
stop_button()

canvas_width = 200
canvas_height = 200
canvas = built_canvas()

cell_width = 10
x1 = 10
y1 = 10
x2 = x1+10
y2 = y1+10
rec = canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2, width=0, fill="green")

counter = 0
master.after(500,update_canvas)

"""
# The code below only gives the final state

for i in range(1,10):
    master.after(500)
    canvas.delete(rec)
    rec = canvas.create_rectangle(x1+i*10,y1+i*10,x2+i*10,y2+i*10, width=0, fill="green")
"""
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in the code. Please replace "I" in the "rec  = " expression in update_canvas()" for "counter". Nevertheless the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tkinter function `after` does two very different things - if you call it like in the section you put between """ """:

`master.after(500)`

This makes your python program wait for half a second, and then continues.

If you call it like your loop in `update_canvas`:

`master.after(500, update_canvas)`

then it returns *immediately*, with no wait, but schedules `update_canvas` to happen half a second into the future.

So the version you have above with

```
 while counter<10:
     canvas.delete(rec)
     rec = canvas.create_rectangle(x1+i*10,y1+i*10,x2+i*10,y2+i*10, width=0, fill="green")
     counter +=1
     master.after(500,update_canvas)
```

Doesn't give the right time delay, since the loop runs through all 10 iterations with no waiting, and schedules update_canvas to happen 10 times, all after half a second from *now*, not half a second from each other.

The version in quotes:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    master.after(500)
    canvas.delete(rec)
    rec = canvas.create_rectangle(x1+i*10,y1+i*10,x2+i*10,y2+i*10, width=0, fill="green")
```

Has a different problem - this runs the loop multiple times, and waits half a second each time, but the window is not even visible yet since you haven't reached `master.mainloop()` - so it animates the object, but you can't see it yet.

To fix this, you need to use the first version that schedules in the future, so you can schedule it and then call `mainloop()`, and then have the first one schedule the next one.

If we do this instead:

```
def update_canvas():
    global counter, rec # global lets you change counter and rec from inside the function - avoids 'Unbound local variable'
    if counter >= 10:
        return #  If the counter is big enough, stop and do nothing more
    else:
        canvas.delete(rec) # Update the rectangle
        i = counter
        rec = canvas.create_rectangle(x1+i*10,y1+i*10,x2+i*10,y2+i*10, width=0, fill="green")
        counter +=1 # Add to the counter so we don't animate forever
        master.after(500,update_canvas) # Schedule the next update for half a second in the future
```

Then it should animate the square. This way the loop is gone, but the first time we call `update_canvas`, the `update_canvas` function itself asks tkinter to call it again later on. Eventually the counter gets big enough, and it doesn't ask for another call and the animation stops.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. And thanks for the explanation why it didn't work. That helped me a lot to understand tkinter and mainloop much better,

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the while loop in `update_canvas()`. Also you do not need to recreate the rectangle, just move it:

```
def update_canvas(counter=0):
    if counter < 10:
        canvas.move(rec, 10, 10)
        master.after(500, update_canvas, counter+1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, moving an object was not my problem. I just wanted to delete and create rectangles on different places of grid as part of a more complex plan. I had reduced the code to what I saw as the core problem. I should have made that more clear in my question. Sorry for that.